# flask app fails when loaded with wsgi, but works fine with dev server

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have my flask app working just great with the dev server when I run it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But when I try to run it with wsgi I get all kinds of "module not installed" errors, and even syntax errors.  Strangely, it shows a different error each time I hit an app route.

on some of the errors, from the output in the apache error log, I can see that it's trying to run 2.7 versions of packages, when I am using 3.4.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
```

I don't know why this is, python 3 is the default on the server and

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.2
```

is the output for every user on the system.  I *am* using virtualenv, but I did follow these instructions for setting up mod_wsgi with virtualenv: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/

my wsgi file looks like this:

```
import sys

activate_this = '/home/flask-dev/es_app/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

print(sys.path)

from searchapp import app as application
```

and that print(sys.path) outputs this when I run it like 'python run.wsgi':

```
['/home/flask-dev/es_app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/home/flask-dev/es_app', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

i.e. a path to the 2.7 packages is nowhere in sight.  Also, all the required modules *are* installed in my virtualenv, which is why it works fine when I run the dev server.

Totally stumped on this.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Apache which Python executable it should use to launch python processes. Without explicit configuration, Apache probably takes the first 'python' present in the system path. (*In fact no, see comments below. The distribution default python is used.*)

Unfortunately, it looks like you need to re-compile mod_wsgi, as the python exe can only be changed by the `configure` script.

http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#multiple-python-versions

In your case: `./configure --with-python=/home/flask-dev/es_app/venv/bin/python`

That's a lot of work for something that should be simple. Usually i just use Apache in reverse-proxy mode (thanks to mod_proxy), and point it to an external WSGI server like Gunicorn (http://gunicorn.org/) or Waitress (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/).

Comment: Good call on recompiling the module - I totally forgot about that. Yes, this whole thing should be simpler.  But I guess that's why flask is still v0.11.I like your idea of using uWSGI, I was curious to know if there's also a resource advantage (or disadvantage)?

Comment: uWSGI ? No i did not mentioned it :) But yes it is another possibility. In all cases you have Apache process and python processes. With Apache + mod_wsgi they are tightly coupled. With mod_proxy + an external WSGI server they are not. I think the consumed resources depend more on the configuration tuning (how many process/threads) than on the kind of WSGI you use.

Comment: Your description is incorrect. When using mod_wsgi it doesn't use the first 'python' present in the system path. Instead mod_wsgi is compiled for a specific Python version and links directly to the Python shared library. The solution is indeed though to reinstall mod_wsgi with a version which is compiled for the Python version that you want to use. Usually a Linux distribution has this for main stream Python versions it provides, so all you need to do is uninstall the mod_wsgi version for Python 2 and install that for Python 3.

Comment: OP should read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html which talks about how to use virtual environments correctly with mod_wsgi and warns about mixing Python versions. As to installing from source code, for easy way of installing mod_wsgi see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi Just use ``pip install`` and then ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to get lines to add to Apache configuration to load module. Ensure you uninstall system mod_wsgi module first.

Comment: Finally, you can always use ``mod_wsgi-express`` from the command line and/or proxy it behind a front end web server. Is no different to using gunicorn or uWSGI.

Comment: Thanks graham.  I think re-compiling mod_wsgi was the missing piece.  I went ahead and did that.  I am still getting errors, but they are path-related, which I think I can debug.  I do have a question...if I include a print statement in my wsgi file (like I did), how can I easily see the output when the server runs it?  do I need to load a logger?

Comment: every answer is there: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html

Comment: Anything output to ``stdout`` or ``stderr`` via ``print()`` or the ``logging`` module, if it is configured to send to ``stdout`` or ``stderr`` (as is recommended under mod_wsgi), will go to the Apache error log.

Comment: cool - thanks again.  Got it all worked out!  thanks for your work on this module.